How to Change Avatar Picture on Fedora Linux Hyprland?
I'm using Fedora Linux with the Hyprland window manager, and I'm trying to change my user avatar picture. In GNOME, there's an easy GUI way to do this, but I can't seem to find a similar option or tool in Hyprland.
System Information:
Fedora Version: 40
Hyprland Version: 0.41.2
Desktop Environment: None (using Hyprland standalone)

Thanks in advance for any assistance!
